# When is an address saved to the customer during checkout?

Tags: magento-enterprise

During onepage checkout, a customer has the option to enter a new shipping address and save this address to their profile.  This functionality is broken (probably due to custom code) and I'm attempting to debug it.

In `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::saveShipping`, a call is made to `$address->setSaveInAddressBook`.  It's my understanding that this flag should cause the address to be saved at the final step of checkout.

What block of code actually causes this address to be saved?  I'd like to debug the save point and work backwards to find my bug, but I can't find the point where the shipping address is saved.

Comment: You've tagged this post both `magento-1.7` and `magento-enterprise` - there is no EE 1.7 release ...

Comment: I removed the CE tag.  I tagged both because the code is the same for EE and CE.  Technically, I'm working in EE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the method `_prepareCustomerQuote()` in `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage` (assuming you're using onepage checkout). It sets the address onto the customer there.

The customer is saved in the method `submitOrder()` in `Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote`.

Comment: Thanks!  Interestingly enough, my problem ended up being the save_in_address_book flag not being populated due to some theme changes.